# Bootstrap different views for mobile and desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a website with bootstrap and I'm using this logic to show columns differently on mobile and desktop version. I'm using classes like .visible-lg and .visible-xs. Is it good practice to do that to make margin between columns different and to show them differently in mobile and desktop version.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <img src="images/strelica.png">
    </div>

     <div class="col-lg-1 visible-lg"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <img src="images/strelica.png">
    </div>       

    <div class="col-lg-1 visible-lg"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 ">
        <img src="images/strelica.png">
    </div>       

    <div class="col-lg-1 visible-lg"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <img src="images/comp.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better (less markup) to use the `offset` class to space the columns. However the empty `visible-xs` is the only way to create spaces between each row...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <img src="//placehold.it/800" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-1">
        <img src="//placehold.it/800" class="img-responsive">
    </div>       
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-1">
        <img src="//placehold.it/800" class="img-responsive">
    </div>       
    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <img src="//placehold.it/800" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/120292